# Calling super to store values, but using subclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, parent, super

Is it possible to use a parent class in order to store common values for a shared method in the super class but still use the individual constructors for the subclasses(i.e. storing an arbitrary value k from the parameters of two constructors of different subclasses into the superclass, yet still calling upon the individual and different constructors from the two subclasses)?

e.g

In sub class:

```
public pictureImpl(Picture source, int x, int y, int height, int width) { 
    super(height, width);
    "rest of constructor using all parameters"
}
```

In super class:

```
public superPicture(int height, int width) {
   heightValue = height;
   widthValue = width;
}
```

Here, would it still be possible to use the part in parentheses for the subclass (i.e. is it possible to call the rest of a constructor even after using super to store values?

Comment: I guess you should make some real examples because from the description it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jack added examples, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common use case for protected constructors of the base class:

```
class Base {
    private final int val;
    protected Base(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
class Derived1 extends Base {
    public Derived1(String name, int val) {
        super(val);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
class Derived2 extends Base {
    public Derived2(int val, Date timestamp) {
        super(val);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: in the constructor for the super class, what do the final and protected do? Thanks!

Comment: @hliu `protected` means you can't construct `Base` directly using this constructor, i.e. `void main(String[] args) {Base b = new Base(1); }` is not going to compile. `final` in the declaration of `val` makes the field read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The method superPicture is public on super class and is inherited for usage into extending class.

You can simple call it.

If you override it you can also access it with super.superPicture(width, height);